# Probability with Power Sets

Tags: probability

> Statement - $\mathcal A$ is a power set of a given set $X$ containing $n$ elements and $P , Q , R$ belongs to $\mathcal A$ ( may or may not be distinct)
>
> Question - if $P \cap Q \cap R$ contain just 1 element , find probability that $P$ also contain just 1 element.

I tried and my answer came out to be $n \times (4/7)^{(n-1)}$

But answer says it should be only $(4/7)^{(n-1)}$. Which I think would be the probability for just a particular 1 element.

Help me in understanding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For $n=2$ your expression gives a probability of $\frac 87$, which cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be arguing that if $P \cap Q \cap R$ consists of only one specific element the chance $P$ consists of only that argument is $\left( \frac 47\right)^{n-1}$, which is correct, then multiplying by $n$ to account for all the elements that might be singleton.  When you account for all the elements the denominator gets a factor $n$ as well, so they divide out.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But please explain why denominator should get a factor of n. What I am doing is Total probability theorem I.e means I first found the probability of just one specific element (let it be 1st element) then 2nd element probability would be same. That's why by adding all probability we get n×(4/7)^(n-1). Which I knew is wrong but can you point out wrong in my thinking process. Thanks :)

Comment: When you compute the number of ways to get the intersection be a single element for the denominator, you also start by counting the number of ways to get a specific element.  When you choose that element, it has to be a member of all three $P,Q,R$.  Each other element has seven possibilities for which sets it is a member of.  Again, you can multiply by $n$ for the total number of ways to get the intersection to be a singleton.  That is the $n$ in the denominator.

Comment: Yes I understood it. Such a silliy mistake. Thanks for your effort. I can't express my happiness in words :).